# Nginx configuration with hashtags

Tags: nginx, proxy

I've a question.
How can I config my nginx for redirecting from url started without hashtags to url started with hashtag. For example "/sign-in" redirect to "/#sign-in". Or "/admin/create" to "/#admin/create".
But I need exclude some addresses, for example, "/api" redirect to "http://someapi.com".
 
I use windows. Thanks!

Comment: Using nginx on windows is a bad idea.

Comment: And what is the problem. What did you try?

Comment: I use angularJS and HTML5 history API. So, when I click on anchor with url "/url", angular with HTML5 handles it and show me page like page with "/#url".

Comment: But when I open link in new tab, angular is not initializing and my app fails. I need to handle this situation using nginx.

Comment: In production we don't use windows and... I don't know what we use in production on server side. May be python handles this situation or may be not. I am just frontend developer.